# How do I register a test discoverer in .net core with csproj

Tags: c#, .net, nunit, .net-core, csproj

After upgrading my nunit test project using dotnet migrate to move to from json to csproj. I can no longer run my tests. I get a message saying:

> No test discoverer is registered to perform discovery of test cases.
>   Register a test discoverer and try again.

for reference here is my csproj file

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

     <PropertyGroup>
         <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
         <TargetFramework>netcoreapp1.1</TargetFramework>
     </PropertyGroup>

     <ItemGroup>
         <ProjectReference Include="../Jsonics/Jsonics.csproj" />
     </ItemGroup>

     <ItemGroup>
         <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version="15.0.0" />
         <PackageReference Include="NUnit" Version="3.6.0" />
         <PackageReference Include="dotnet-test-nunit" Version="3.4.0-beta-3" />
     </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

The following page tells you what to do for xunit and mstest but not for nunit:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/core/tools/project-json-to-csproj#testrunner

How do I register a test discoverer?

Comment: I suspect we need a newer version of dotnet-test-nunit.

Comment: FWIW, You can run the tests with latest version of NCrunch (http://www.ncrunch.net).

Answer (score 1):

They are updating the adapter, see [this tweet](https://twitter.com/rprouse/status/839461148600774659).

Comment: Is this fixed now?

Comment: A branch is supposed to work I think. There is also a issue opened. Don't think there is a package released yet.

Comment: I see that; the lead developer has posted a meantime workaround.

Answer (score 1):

The current workaround is to use NUnitLite to make your tests run in a standalone exe. You can read how to do so [here](http://www.alteridem.net/2015/11/04/testing-net-core-using-nunit-3/).